# How do I fix two bugs for my jQuery form Validation code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

My code basically adds a class error if field is invalid and if the field is valid, the error class is removed and form is submitted normally.

I am having trouble figuring out two small bugs for the form validation code I created.

Bugs listed below:

1) If you enter the correct content within one field, and click submit, the length of the error class does not update on first submit click. It takes two submit clicks for the length to update. (view console.log)

2) If you change the content of the input field and click submit (all works well, error class is removed) BUT if you decide to delete your updated text & leave the field blank, the error class does not get re-applied.

Would be great if I can get some assistance solving this.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aRxSP/6/)

```
$('form.requiredFields').submit(function(e) {

    var req = $(this).find('.req'),
        validateEmail = function(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        };

    req.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            defaultVal = $this.prop('defaultValue'); //cache default val

        //checks for validation errors
       if (  ( $this.hasClass('email') && !validateEmail( $this.val() ) ) ||
             ( defaultVal === $this.val() || $this.val() === '' || $this.val().length < 3 )
       ) 
       {
          $this.addClass('error');
       } else {
          $this.removeClass('error req');
       }

    });

    console.log(req.length);

    if ( req.length === 0 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like dc5 said for #2 don't remove the req class.

And for #1 - You're looking for errors (.req) before it is removed.

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aRxSP/7/). It is an example how your code work but maybe you can find a cleaner solution.

```
$('form.requiredFields').submit(function(e) {

    var req = $(this).find('.req'), errorCheck = 0,
        validateEmail = function(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        };

    req.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            defaultVal = $this.prop('defaultValue'); //cache default val

        //checks for validation errors
       if (  ( $this.hasClass('email') && !validateEmail( $this.val() ) ) ||
             ( defaultVal === $this.val() || $this.val() === '' || $this.val().length < 3 )
       ) 
       {
          $this.addClass('error');
       } else {
          $this.removeClass('error');
       }

    });

    errorCheck = $(this).find('.error');
    console.log(errorCheck.length);

    if ( errorCheck.length === 0 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! Works perfectly and answers all my questions :)

Comment: UPDATE: Cleaner solution here: 

https://github.com/Shivambh28/ezValidation/blob/master/ezValidation.js

Answer (score 1):

for #2, You are moving the 'req' class as well as the 'error' class when clearing the error.  The next time through the call, the input is no longer found through your selector `$(this).find('.req')`

For #1 - I don't understand the problem as you have described it.

Comment: Thanks dc5 for your input on #2 bug. Will definitely not make that mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I made it easier for you, actually your code is a mess,

here is a fiddle:

[**Jsfiddle validate Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8hxmv/1/)

**CODE:**

```
$('#submit_form').click(function() {
    var flag = 0;
    var count = 0,
        total = $(".req").length;
    var validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }      
    $('.req').each(function(){
        count++; 
        if($(this).attr('id')=='email') {
            if(!validateEmail($(this).val())){ $(this).addClass('error');  flag = 1; } 
                else { $(this).removeClass('error'); } }

        if($(this).attr('id')=='name') {
            if($(this).val().length < 3){ $(this).addClass('error');  flag = 1; } 
                else { $(this).removeClass('error'); } }

        if($(this).attr('id')=='com') {
            if($(this).val().length < 3&&$(this).val()!=''){ $(this).addClass('error');  flag = 1; } 
            else { $(this).removeClass('error'); } }

        if ( total==count&&flag<1) { alert('submit'); }
    });
});
```

**Validation rules**:

1. name - must be bigger then 2.
2. email - true on pattern match function.
3. comment - if typed, must be bigger the 2 chars (just to understand how can it be done).

If this example is not clear or you need more help don't hesitate... I'm bored.

Comment: Hey Shomi, Thanks a lot for the input. I originally had multiply if statements like your code but it was getting out of control when sites have multiple forms really long forms. Which is why I created my own method of applying the req class and validating everything automatically.